# My scraped data is empty (Rails and mechanize)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, rake, rake-task

I am writing a simple script to scrape data from this link: https://www.congress.gov/members.

The script will go through each link of the member, follow that link, and scrape data from that link. This script is a .rake file on Ruby on Rails application.

Below is the script:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'date'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

module OpenSSL
    module SSL
    remove_const :VERIFY_PEER
    end
end

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

I_KNOW_THAT_OPENSSL_VERIFY_PEER_EQUALS_VERIFY_NONE_IS_WRONG = nil


task :testing do

    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get("https://www.congress.gov/members")

    page_links = page.links_with(href: %r{^/member/\w+})

    product_links = page_links[0...2]

    products = product_links.map do |link|

      product = link.click

      state = product.search('td:nth-child(1)').text
      website = product.search('.member_website+ td').text

      {
        state: state,
        website: website
      }

    end

    puts JSON.pretty_generate(products)
end
```

and below is the output when i ran this script/file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression does not match links. 
Try this: `page_links = page.links_with(href: %r{.*/member/\w+})`

You can validate regular expressions here: http://rubular.com/